# Find lines with same starting "cell"?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with thousands of lines, each line has the same format `<some text here> - <some more text here>`. I want to make use of regular expressions to find consecutive lines with the same `<some text here>` at the beginning.

My approach:

```
^(.*?) - .*$\r\n$1
```

Line start, followed by a group containing any number of characters until the combination "space hyphen space", any number of more characters (until line end, which is not matched by dot, I double-checked), followed by the (Windows) newline, followed by the first group.

Looks right to me, however, it doesn't match :( Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy, found the answer myself: Notepad++ uses `\1` as the group replacement sequence, not `$1` :-(

Comment: You can use `$1` in the replacement pattern as well as `\1`, but in-pattern backreferences only allow ``\`` notation.